# I am getting this error while compiling this code "Time Limit Exceeded Your program took more time than expected."

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, time-limiting

I keep getting this error while compiling this code

Time Limit Exceeded

Your program took more time than expected.Time Limit Exceeded
Expected Time Limit 1.02sec
Hint : Please optimize your code and submit again

##Write the function completely

```
    def isPrime(number):

        for i in range(2, number):
            if (number % i) == 0:
                return False
                break
        return True


       #Driver Code Starts.


    import math



    def main():
        testcases = int(input()) #testcases
        while(testcases > 0):
            number = int(input())
            print(isPrime(number)) 
            testcases -= 1
    


     if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

the function isPrime is giving an error please give me the solution for this

Comment: You don't need to test every value between `2` and `number` - this is where you can improve your program's performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`for i in range(2, number):`

with

`for i in range(2, (number/2)+1):`

Also there is no use of `break` in this code so remove that as well.